# How to convert date string to date in oracle

Tags: string, oracle, date

[Screenshot of query executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZOz2.png) The date string in '**Sat Oct 29 10:47:50 CDT 2016**' has to be converted to date/timestamp format in oracle query. I need to extract only date and time from it. I tried using to to_date() but didn't work. Can one someone please help.

Error: 
ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0
01841. 00000 -  "(full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0"
*Cause:    Illegal year entered
*Action:   Input year in the specified range

Comment: Please post the `to_date()` syntax you used. Which format did you use? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34924

Comment: Please show in the question how did you use `to_date` function.?

Comment: @Wernfried Please give a solution then if you have one.  I have never even used Oracle hence I could not test my answer.

Comment: Order_date has the string format of timestamp of order received as mentioned above and query is --  select to_date(order_date ,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from table_name where rownum<=3;

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(
   REGEXP_REPLACE('Sat Oct 29 10:47:50 CDT 2016', '^\w+ (\w+ \d+ \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).+(\d{4})', '\1 \2'), 
      'Mon DD HH24:MI:SS YYYY')
FROM DUAL
```

Data type `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` does not support any time zone information, you have to remove this part before you can do the conversion.

Comment: This extracts only date from it, we need time also from it.. the DB column has date stored as "**Sat Oct 29 10:47:50 CDT 2016**" in string format and we need to pull the records between 15min/30min interval by querying on the string colum

Comment: No, it also reads the time as by `HH24:MI:SS`. Check `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` setting of your current session.

Comment: Yeah.."HH24:MI:SS" this reads the time, but somehow the output didn't return the time, it only shows . And the NLS_DATE_FORMAT is "DD-MON-RR" am not aware of how this effects the query output? query screenshot [https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZOz2.png]

Comment: `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` defines the default output format of `DATE` values. Change it (e.g. to `yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss`) or define the output format explicitly by `TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(REGEXP_REPLACE(...., 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')`